# DolphinDB: how to perform iterative operations based on previous results using SQL statements?

Tags: dolphindb, accumulate

I intend to calculate a column named “position“ with an initial value of 0. The calculation logic is: when “position” = 0 and “ov95” = 1, “position” returns 1; when “position” = 1 and “ov70” = 0, “position” returns 0. That is, the calculation of “position“ in the k-th row requires the value of “position“ in the (k-1)th row. Is it possible to achieve this using SQL?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think `accumulate` could perform your calculation: implement your position calucation function, and then input your table (which contains `ov70` and `ov95` columns) and the init value (0 in your case). Then you will get the position vector.